# How to Change TabPage Position in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I have six tabs on my Windows application. I need to put tab #6 after tab #2, how can i do it?
I couldn't drag the tab to the location i want! The 5 tabs are full of controls that took long time to name and design. Any idea how to move last tab and place it after 3rd tab?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to arrange the tabs in a TabControl, access the property dialog for the TabControl and find the "TabPages" property. Clicking on the little button next to the value field will display a dialog which will allow you to control the properties and position of each tab in the TabControl.

[TabPages Property http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/6334/tabeditor.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/6334/tabeditor.png)

Answer (score 3):

Although an answer is there: I thought this picture may speak few more words ;)

1. Click on Tab Control
2. Go to Properties Window
3. Click on Tab Page as highlighted in blue
4. Voila! The TabPage Collection Editor allows you to perform what you need. It's intuitive.

[image]